# Excel - Is it possible to create nested 2D stacked bar chart?

Tags: excel, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a "nested" 2D stacked bar chart in excel but I only got until stacking the columns. Unable to show "work %" inside "Used %". Is there a way to accomplish this in excel? I seen a similar example but that was in BI and not in excel.

**Update:**
Please note that "Work" is a subset of "Used".
Total =100 & Used = 50, then Used % = 50%
Used = 50 & Work = 50 , then Work % = 50% (of Used).
Hope this clarifies.

```
Name    Type    Total   Used    Work    Used %  Work %
Mike    Sport1  100     50      25      50      50.00
Mike    Sport2  175     75      50      42.86   66.67
Mike    Sport3  50      40      10      80      25.00
Mike    Sport4  200     110     40      55      36.36
Rita    Sport1  75      25      10      33.33   40.00
Rita    Sport2  150     100     80      66.67   80.00
Rita    Sport3  100     75      35      75      46.67
Rita    Sport4  125     100     80      80      80.00
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting an approach further down, but your question needs a lot of clarification. The clarification would normally go into a series of me writing comments and you responding by editing your question and providing more details.

I don't feel like going through this rigmarole right now, so, please read my questions for clarification, try to understand what I'm after and then go and edit your question to provide the required detail.

My questions to you:

What is the information you want to derive from the data? What question are you posing to the data that the chart should answer?

Your data table does not make sense. The "total" column totals --what exacty--? How come "used" is 50 and "work" is 25 but Used% is 50 and Work% is also 50?

```
Name    Type    Total   Used    Work    Used %  Work %
Mike    Sport1  100     50      25      50      50.00
```

Please edit your question and either amend the data or explain how it all hangs together.

What data do you want to chart? The scribbles on your scan are less than conclusive.

My suggestion:

These questions aside, you can create a stacked column chart with the data you want to display. You may need to create a **helper table** as the data source for the chart, just so everything is in the correct place for easy selection and rendering.

Whether or not something is a percentage or part of a bigger unit can be shown by formatting the colors of the data points, and with data labels.

You can add data labels to any series and then edit the labels to receive their values from spreadsheet cells. The whole thing can be automated with VBA.

If you don't want to write that kind of VBA yourself (which is understandable) you can download the free XY Chart Labeler tool by Rob Bovey [here](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm). It is ill-named and can actually add labels to any chart type.

I'm aware that this is not a complete answer. I expect you to edit your question with the missing information, so I can subsequently edit my answer to supply a real answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and feedback. I have updated my question. I'm trying to show the Used % & Work % in a stacked bar but the scribbles are the best I could show at this time. I'm not into VBA programming and trying to achieve this in Excel. I downloaded the XY Chart Labeler but could not use it to solve my problem. Thanks.